# EXC_BAD_ACCESS on NSString stringWithFormat

Tags: ios, nsstring, exc-bad-access

On my iOS app I receive a EXC_BAD_ACCESS error on this row :

```
temperature.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ °C", tempC];
```

the error is the following:

```
*** -[CFString class]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x15e4a2c0
```

Can you help me?

Comment: When you stepped through this in the debugger, did you see any objects in your program formerly living at the address specified in the message?

Comment: You need to show more code. What is `tempC`? Where and how is it used?

Comment: Presumably tempC is deallocated.  Spend a little time studying storage management in Objective-C & iOS -- it's non-trivial and you MUST learn it if you expect to do any iOS programming.